# Emulator's showing my images. But my phone can't

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I can see images from Firebase in emulator,but when i publish to my phone can't see images in phone. I'm using ***Firebase*** realtime database and Picasso library. I store images Url in database.I use Picasso to show images. But I can see images in  emulator,can't see mobile phone. I try to use "with" function but code doesn't allow it. How can I fix this ?

```
public class IngredientsAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter <IngredientsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
**Context** mContext;
ArrayList<Ingredients> mIngredientsArrayList;
CustomItemClickListener mListener;
public IngredientsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ingredients> 
ingredientsArrayList, CustomItemClickListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    mIngredientsArrayList = ingredientsArrayList;
    mListener = listener;
}



   @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = 
    LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.soup_cardview, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onItemClick(view, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.soupName.setText(mIngredientsArrayList.get(position).getName());
   Picasso.get().load(mIngredientsArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.soupImage);
}

**@Override**
public int getItemCount() {
    return mIngredientsArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView soupName;
    ImageView soupImage;
    TextView soupIngredients;
    TextView soupDetail;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        soupName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        soupImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

    }  }
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android{
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cd.com.cook"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

}
apply plugin:** 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Do you have any warning in Logcat ? By the way, you should use Glide instead of Picasso, which is the new reference for image loading.

Comment: I change Picasso.Here is warn message :                                                        class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model.

Comment: It seems the URL you are using is null. It may be because your APK file is different between the one you use on an emulator and the one you use on your phone (app id, signing config, etc.). Therefore, Firebase doesn't send you the right data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a max image size that can be rendered by device with turned on hardware acceleration. This size is device dependent. If bitmap is bigger than this size - it won't be rendered.

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```